# Select paths based on information of linked nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have following problem:
I want to select paths nodes with type A. But I do not want all paths, only ones with specific properties. The problem is, that in our datamodel these properties are stored in a separate node of type AD. For the start and endpoint everything works fine. And I think I also have worked out the general structure as this query here works perfectly fine.

```
MATCH (n:A)-->(ad:AD) WHERE ad.name='AD0'
WITH n AS start
MATCH (n:A)-->(ad:AD) WHERE ad.name='AD3'
WITH n AS end, start
MATCH p = (start) -[:L*0..10]-> (end)
WHERE ALL (x in nodes(p) [1..-1] WHERE ( (x.name STARTS WITH 'ad1' OR x.name STARTS WITH 'ad2')))
return p
```

The problem here is, that I get the property for the intermediate nodes out of the nodes of type A, which will not pe possible in our final model. For testing I added a property to A containing the information normally stored in AD.

The result should only contain nodes of type A linked to nodes of type AD and AD.name should be AD0... AD3, but I want to exclude nodes of type A linked to AD nodes with AD.name='AD4' for example.
For this I tried the following query, but it only returns path containing nodes A linked to nodes AD with AD.name = AD0 or AD3.

```
MATCH (n:A)-->(ad:AD WHERE ad.name='AD0'
WITH n AS start
MATCH (n:A)-->(ad:AD) WHERE ad.name='AD3'
WITH n AS end, start
MATCH (n:AD) WITH n AS ad, end, start //somehow needed otherwise I cannot use AD in the where clause
MATCH p = (start) -[:L*0..]-> (end)
WHERE ALL (
    x in nodes(p) [1..-1] WHERE (
        ((x)-->(ad:AD))
        AND 
        (ad.name ='AD1' OR ad.name='AD2')
    )
)
return p
```

Any idea why paths containing only nodes of type A linked to nodes of type AD with AD.name =AD1 or AD2 are not returned?

Comment: First thing: in the line `MATCH (n:AD) WITH n AS ad, sinks, sources` you are not passing `start` and `end` to the next context. I believe you should change this line to `MATCH (n:AD) WITH n AS ad, sinks, sources, start, end` and try again.

Comment: sorry, there was a mixup, sinks sources are start end now, corrected the code above

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. No idea if there is a better way, but I had to put my intermediate nodes in a seperate list, otherwise I cannot use it in the where part of the WHERE ALL clause. The working code looks like this:

```
MATCH (n:A)-->(ad:AD WHERE ad.name='AD0'
WITH n AS start
MATCH (n:A)-->(ad:AD) WHERE ad.name='AD3'
WITH n AS end, start
MATCH (n:A)-->(ad:AD) WHERE (ad.name IN ['AD1', 'AD2'])
WITH collect(n) AS intermediates, sinks, sources 
MATCH p = (start) -[:L*0..]-> (end)
WHERE ALL (
    x IN nodes(p) [1..-1] WHERE (
        x IN intermediates
    )
)
return p
```